# Generate permutations of multi array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

I would like to generate all permutations of elements in a multi array in javascript (or the algorithm):

Input:

```
[
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['h', 'i']
]
```

Output:

```
[
  ['a', 'e', 'h'],
  ['a', 'e', 'i'],
  ['a', 'f', 'h'],
  ...
  ['d', 'g', 'i']
]
```

**Note**: I don't want the permutations of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'] because i don't want results like: ['a', 'b', 'c'].

**Note2**: I'm only interested in solutions that support input of N-dimension array.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)

Comment: Loop through all array in the array and get a list of unique item. After, it should be easy to get permutations of your size as we already have so many posts on how to get permutations.

Comment: @Attersson In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript the output is the permutations of each array element, here the output is the permutations of the inner elements of the elements of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function mutate(array) {
   if(array.length === 1)
      return array[0].map(el => [el]);
   const mutations = mutate(array.slice(1));
   const result = [];
   for(const el of array[0])
     for(const rest of mutations)
       result.push([el, ...rest]);
   return result;
}
```

This is a recursive approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you like functional programming, you can use `lift` on Array type. In my case, I've used [RamdaJS](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#liftN) for the sake of simplicity:

```js
const input = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['h', 'i']
]

const output = R.lift ( ( x, y, z ) => [ x, y, z ] ) ( ...input )

console.log( output )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a vanilla JavaScript `lift3` implementation:

```js
const input = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['h', 'i']
]

const flatten = array => [].concat.apply ( [], array )

// Array#flatMap please! ;-)
const ap = funs => array => flatten ( funs.map ( f => array.map ( f ) ) )

const lift3 = f => array1 => array2 => array3 => 
                ap ( ap ( array1.map ( f ) ) ( array2 ) ) ( array3 )

const output = lift3 ( x => y => z => [ x, y, z ] ) ( input[0] ) ( input[1] ) ( input[2] )

console.log( output )
```

Comment: do you need to specify the length and take n parameter for it (and the corresponding array)?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, I've switched to `R.lift` which infers this for you. BTW, I prefer fixed arity functions (i.e. `lift3`)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
var d = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i']],
    processor = array => {
         var result = [],
             iter = p => p.length < array.length
                ? array[p.length].forEach(v => iter(p.concat(v)))
                : result.push(p);

        iter([]);
        return result;
    };

console.log(processor(d).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A shorter approach

```js
var d = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i']],
    result = d.reduce(
        (a, b) => a.reduce(
            (r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))),
            []
        )
    );

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be interested in is a cartesian product of the sets. The length of the output will be the product of the sets' lengths and we can derive the list index of each element in an arbitrary output list by the following method:

```js
// i is the zero-based ouput-list index
// p is the product of input set lengths
function unrank(i, input, p){
  let output_list = new Array(input.length);

  for (let k=0; k<input.length; k++){
    p = Math.floor(p / input[k].length);
    let m = Math.floor(i / p);
    i = i - m * p;
    output_list[k] = input[k][m];
  }
  
  return output_list;
}

var input = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['h', 'i']
];

// Output
var prod = input.map(x => x.length).reduce((a, b) => a * b);

console.log(unrank(23, input, prod));
console.log(unrank(11, input, prod));
```

To list them all, loop over the indexes from 0 to (product of input set lengths - 1).